# Question about this integral $\int \left| g\left( y\right) \right| \int \left| f\left( x-y\right) \right| dx\,dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have seen this in my script without proof:

> $$\int \left| g\left( y\right) \right| \int \left| f\left( x-y\right) \right| dx\,dy = \int \left| g\left( y\right) \right| dy\int \left| f\left( x\right) \right| dx.$$

Is this true?

Comment: For definite integrals over the entire real $xy$-plane, yes. (Consider the substitution $(u,v)=(x-y,y)$ and then note that the names for $u,v$ are irrelevant in a definite integral.)

Comment: I think you could be more specific: as long as the $x$ integral is over the entire real line, this would be true. I think the domain for the $y$ integral could be arbitrary.

Comment: So $\int \left| g\left( y\right) \right| \int ^{\infty }_{-\infty }\left| f\left( x\right) \right| dxdy = \int \left| g\left( y\right) \right| dy\int ^{\infty }_{-\infty }\left| f\left( x\right) \right| dx$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider change of variable $x' = x-y$. Then for any $y$, $$\int |f(x-y)|\, dx = \int |f(x')| \, d x' = \int |f(x)|\, dx.$$ 
Therefore, $$\int |g(y)| \left(\int |f(x-y)|\, dx\right)dy = \int |g(y)| \left(\int |f(x)|\, dx\right)dy.$$
Observe that $\int |f(x)|\, dx$ is a constant, so we can pull it out of the integral and obtain the desired result.